# Can't run Safari or Chrome, while Charles is running

Tags: macos, charles-proxy

I use Charles 4.1.4.And I set the Charles proxy config as follow.

[image: proxies]. 
[image: Mac OS proxy].

And network proxy change to.

[image: network proxy].

when I browser in safari or chrome, it doesn't work.And charles showed as pic.

[image: charles display]

All connections from browser were failed.

Thanks for all suggestions!

Comment: Hey man, I am having the same issue. Have you solved it and in case you did, how?

Comment: Hi is this issue is solved by anyone of you , if yes please help me out.....